# probability - pair of dice is rolled

Tags: probability

A pair of dice is rolled and the sum is determined. The probability that a sum of 5 is rolled before a sum of 8 is rolled in a sequence of rolls of the dice is ____.

The given answer is 4/9.
[Probability sum of 5 before sum of 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828255/probability-sum-of-5-before-sum-of-7)
I have found this link as well but I want to know where I am going wrong.
My approach:
Here 2 events are independent. Getting a sum of 5 won't be dependent on getting sum of 8 in next roll. so the problem reduces to probability of getting a sum equal to 5. Hence the probability is equal to 4/36 = 1/9. Even if you assume P(A/B) where A is the the event where sum is 5 and B is the event sum of 8. then P(A/B) = P(A) —- events are independent.

why to apply bayes theorem?  what mistake I am doing, aren't this 2 events independent?

Comment: Your argument makes no sense.  Why on earth should the probability of getting a $5$ first be the probability of getting a $5$?

Comment: By your reasoning, the probability that you get the $8$ first would be the probability of getting an $8$, so $\frac 5{36}$.  But note that $\frac 5{36}+\frac 4{36}<1$.

Comment: "*then $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ --- events are independent*"  You should rethink this.  Think hard about what "$A$" represents and what "$B$" represents here.  If by thinking of $A$ as the event that a sum of five is rolled on the first attempt, and $B$ as the event that a sum of eight is rolled on the second attempt (*and attempts continue even after the first time a sum of 8 is rolled*) then yes $A$ will be independent of $B$.  Neither of these events seem directly applicable to this problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the events $A=$ {sum of $5$}, $B=$ {sum of 8} and $C=$ {sum of non-$5$ or non-$8$).

On the first roll: $P(A)=\color{red}{\frac4{36}}; P(B)=\frac5{36}; P(C)=\frac{27}{36}$. If the event $A$ happens, we stop at the first roll. If $B$ happens, we fail, so ignore it. If $C$ happens, we keep rolling.

On the second roll: $P(C_1\cap A_2)=P(C_1)\cdot P(A_2|C_1)=P(C_1)\cdot P(A_2)=\color{blue}{\frac{27}{36}\cdot \frac4{36}}$. Again as above, we act upon the results of the three events.

On the third roll: $P(C_1\cap C_2\cap A_3)=\cdots=P(C_1)\cdot P(C_2)\cdot P(A_3)=\color{green}{\left(\frac{27}{36}\right)^2\cdot \frac4{36}}$. And so on. We get the following geometric series:
$$\begin{align}P(A \ \text{before} \ B)&=\color{red}{\frac4{36}}+\color{blue}{\frac{27}{36}\cdot \frac4{36}}+\color{green}{\left(\frac{27}{36}\right)^2\cdot \frac4{36}}+\cdots=\\
&=\frac4{36}\left(1+\frac{27}{36}+\left(\frac{27}{36}\right)^2+\cdots\right)=\\
&=\frac4{36}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{27}{36}}=\\
&=\frac{4}{36}\cdot \frac{36}{9}=\\
&=\frac49.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

It certainly isn't true that the probability of getting a $5$ first is just the probability of getting a $5$.  To see that, suppose you were asked for the probability of getting a $5$ before a $9$.  You'd still get $\frac 19$ but since a roll of $5$ is just as likely as a roll of $9$ the answer must be $\frac 12$ by symmetry.

You can modify your argument to make it work.  Ignore every roll other than an $8$ or a $5$.  Then there are $9$ rolls which have meaning, and $4$ of those yield a $5$ so the answer is $\frac 49$.

Comment: Yes, this make sense. I didn't consider the multiple rolls. "Then there are 9 rolls which have meaning, and 4 of those yield a 5 so the answer is 4/9". I didn't get this line could you please explain?
and also when to apply bayes theorem.

Comment: The point is that you can ignore every throw that isn't an $8$ or a $5$.  That only leaves $9$ throws (the ones that give either $8$ or $5$).  Each of those are equally likely so the probability that any given meaningful throw (including the first meaningful throw) is a $5$ is $\frac 49$.  I don't see this problem as a Bayes' problem.  At no point am I revising my estimate of a probability.

Comment: To elaborate:  one uses Bayes when one gets new information which provides some evidence one way or another.  That evidence then causes us to re-estimate the relevant probabilities and Bayes gives us a good way to do that.  For this problem, there is never any evidence of anything until the game is decided.

Comment: This time I got it. there exist 9 possibilities which gives either sum 5 or 8. We need to concentrate on that ignoring all other outcomes and among them getting sum 5 only matters which has 4 possibilities hence 4/9. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes!  that's the point exactly.  If you want an exercise in using this principle try to answer the old gambler's question:  "rolling a pair of dice sequentially, what's the probability that you'll get a $6$ and an $8$ before you get two $7's$?"

Answer (score 1):

A general technique to solve such problems where we have infinitely many independent trials and two disjoint events $A$ and $B$, where each trial we have $P(A)=p$, and $P(B)=q$ with $p+q \le 1$. Let us denote the chance that doing trials until $A$ or $B$ occurs, we stop at event $A$ without having seen $B$.

Then conditioning on the outcome of the first trial $X_1$:

$$x = P(A \text{ before } B| X_1 \in A)P(X_1 \in A) + P(A \text{ before } B| X_1 \in B)P(X_1 \in B) + P(A \text{ before } B| X_1 \notin A \cup B)P(X_1 \notin A\cup B)$$

We can use that $P(A \text{ before } B| X_1 \in A) = 1$ (we immediately have $A$ happening so we "win") and $P(A \text{ before } B| X_1 \in B)P(X_1 \in B) = 0$ (we have event $B$ so we stop and "lose") and by definition $P(X_1 \in A) = p$, $P(X_1 \in B)=q$ and $P(X_1 \notin A \cup B)$ means that neither $A$ nor $B$ occurred, and this happens with chance $1-p-q$. Also the probability $P(A \text{ before } B| X_1 \notin A \cup B)$ is just $x$ again, because if the first trial gives no stop condition $A$ or $B$, it's just the same situation as we had before the very first trial, and so the same probability that $A$ occurs before $B$.

So $$x=p\cdot 1 + q\cdot 0+x(1-p-q)$$ or $$(p+q)x =p$$ or $$x=\frac{p}{p+q}$$
Similarly, the probability that $B$ occurs before $A$ is $\frac{q}{p+q}$, together $1$.

In your case $A$ is throwing a $5$ which has probability $\frac{4}{36}$ and $B$ is throwing $8$ which has probability $\frac{5}{36}$.

The formula then gives $\frac{\frac{4}{36}}{\frac{4}{36} + \frac{5}{36}} = \frac{4}{9}$ as it should.

Comment: Thank you so much Henno.

Answer (score 0):

$4/36$ only accounts for the probability of getting $5$ **on the first roll**. This is not the only way to roll a $5$ before an $8$. You could also roll a $5$ on the second roll. This requires rolling something which is not an $8$ on the first roll, so this probability is 
$$
(1-9/36)\cdot(4/36)
$$
Your result is missing this factor, and more (seeing a $5$ for the first time on the third, fourth, etc roll).

The reason to apply Baye's theorem is that the last roll in this process, the roll where you finally see a $5$ or $8$, behaves like a single roll *conditional* on the result being either $5$ or $8$. That is,
$$
P(5\text{ before }8)=P(\text{first roll is }5|\text{ first roll is }5\text{ or }8)
$$
which is where Baye's comes in.

Comment: Okay I got it. I was only considering for the first roll, and never think of the fact that in first attempt if it doesn't occur then I need to keep on rolling till getting a 5 or 8. which makes both event dependent, can you please elaborate on this step how you got (1-5/56).(4/46)?

Comment: You have some typographical errors in your calculation.

Comment: @swapnil Fixed, does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes got it. thank you. Even I had first though it might be a typographical error.

Comment: Also for the second roll sum can't be 5 or 8 in the first roll. hence it becomes (27/36) - for not getting 5 or 8 in the first roll. and now in the second roll it can get sum 5 so 4/36. Hence for second time it will be (27/36)(4/36). what you have done is (1-5/36) I think it should have been (1-9/36). because when won't get 5 or 8 in the first roll then only we will roll for the second time.